# Map EBS Volume to Jenkins Home for a Packer Build

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer, aws-ebs

I'm using:

Packer v1.31.1
Amazon Linux 2 Base AMI

**Concept**

When I bake my AMI with Packer I want to create an encrypted EBS volume that contains the contents of the JENKINS_HOME path.  My current way of thinking is that I should be able to create an EBS volume that I can mount to a particular path on the Linux filesystem (`/var/jenkins_home/` in this case)

**What I've done so far**

I've added the below snippet to my packer template, to create the EBS Volume.

```
"ami_block_device_mappings":
{
    "device_name":  "/dev/sdh",
    "encrypted ":   true,
    "volume_size":  "10",
    "volume_type":  "gp2"
}
```

**Questions**

1. Am I approaching this problem in the right way?
2. If so, how do you map an EBS Volume to a path on the host

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Am I approaching this problem in the right way?
```

Yes this is a good solution.

```
2. If so, how do you map an EBS Volume to a path on the host?
```

Add it to `/etc/fstab`, see [fstab (5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html). And then mount it.